# Detecting iOS lack of scroll event in Modernizr?

Tags: ios, modernizr, browser-feature-detection

The way iOS currently handles the onscroll event is described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7). Basically instead of sending multiple onscroll events as the page/element is being scrolled it sends one onscroll event after the page/element has stopped scrolling.

This creates different issues when scripting a dynamic website, and fallbacks are needed to deal with it.

My question is if there is a [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) style way of dealing with this "lack of a feature". The other way of dealing with it would be to detect what device is being used, which is not really ideal (future – iOS 7 comes and all of a sudden supports it for all devices and my website still displays fallback).

Answer (score 1):

This is just not detectable at this stage.
See:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/Undetectables

> whether a scroll wheel event is coming from a continuous device like a trackpad or the Magic Mouse or from a traditional clicking scroll wheel (in webkit).

Comment: I was aiming to detect the scroll event on iOS (or other devices not sending the onscroll event the way we are used to) rather than detecting what type of PC mouse is used.

Comment: What type of scroll event gets sent depends on what type of device is used ti initiate the scroll action (by which I mean both scrolling devices where the screen is held in your hand and devices where a proxy is manipulated to provide scrolling, such as a mouse). Rikkles is correct, this is currently undetectable in as fine a granulation as you desire. The only alternative is to look for iOS and update your script if/when it changes.